# Second hop in PowerShell Remoting over SSL

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have configured 2 machines with HTTPS WinRM listener. The certificates are self signed. Individually, WinRM over SSL works fine on both machines with `Enter-PSSession` and `Invoke-Command`. But when I do nested sessions the 2nd hops throws error `"Access is denied."` The design is 1 public IP and 1 private address:

Internet > 88.88.88.88 > 192.168.1.10

```
$user = "administrator"
$pass = "P@55w0rd!"
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pass -Force
$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $secure

$Options = New-PsSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "88.88.88.88" -Credential $creds -SessionOption $Options -UseSSL -ScriptBlock {
    $env:COMPUTERNAME

    $user = "admin2"
    $pass = "P@SSW)RD!"
    $secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pass -Force
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $secure

    $Options = New-PsSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck

    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $env:COMPUTERNAME } -ComputerName "192.168.1.10" -Credential $cred -UseSSL -SessionOption $Options 
}
```

Output:

> hop1name

Error Message:

> [192.168.1.10] Connecting to remote server 192.168.1.10 failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>
> + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (192.168.1.10:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
>
> + PSComputerName        : 88.88.88.88

Comment: Look up "Powershell double hop" There's hundreds of articles on this.

Comment: `$user  = '192.168.1.10\admin2'`?

Comment: It works, thanks a lot man, really appreciated. I just found that it works with `$user = ".\admin2"` too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. All credit goes to [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron).

Solution:

`$user  = '192.168.1.10\admin2'`

Or better way:

`$user  = '.\admin2'`